# Custom Big Notification In API level 10

Tags: android, notifications, custom-view

I'm using a Custom View for notifications.
In this case, I know that for a big size notification, I have to use `bigContentView` and set a big view for it.
Every thing is good in API 16, But my app minimum SDK is API level 10 and `bigContentView` is not supported in API level 10.

```
myNotification= notification.setContentTitle("some string")
            .setContentText("some text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .build();

RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(MyApp.getAppContext().getPackageName(),
            R.layout.custom_notification_layout);

myNotification.bigContentView=notificationView; //Error in this line!
```

Is there another way to display big layout for a custom notification?
Or is a older version of `bigContentView`?

Comment: bigContentView Added in API level 16 > http://www.androiddev.ir/reference/android/app/Notification.html

Comment: Thanks @Criss but my app min sdk was 10. Unfortunately API 10 doesn't support big view, but for a custom view i used `Notification.contentView`.

Comment: Hi ! Have you found your answer ? I don't think it's possible Big views were introduced in Android 4.1, and they're not supported on older devices( http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html) second paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big view for notifications were introduced in and android 4.1 and they're not supported on older devices. (as @Pop Tudor commented)

- We can use it by `bigContentView(RemteView)` for notifications if api level is upper than 15.
- In API 15 or lower, we can only set custom view for notifications by `contentView(View)` method.